# почему не сработает событие Click C# в некоторых случаях?

Tags: c#

Поясните пожалуйста, почему не сработает событие Click C# в некоторых случаях?
Допустим, тут:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms; 
System.Windows.Forms

namespace WorkFiles
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        /**
         * Кнопка вывода простого сообщения
         */
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Текст сообщения", "Заголовок сообщения", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
        }

        /**
         * Кнопка вывода сообщения с выбором
         */
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Нравиться ли вам сайт vbbook.ru", "vbbook.ru", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

            if (result == DialogResult.No) //Если нажал нет
            {
                MessageBox.Show("vbbook.ru не нравиться");
            }

            if (result == DialogResult.Yes) //Если нажал Да
            {
                MessageBox.Show("vbbook.ru нравиться!!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А в Events у кнопки на Click прописано, что нужно вызывать соответствующий метод? В InitializeComponent формы есть строка this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);

Comment: Эээх, моя любимая русский язык! Здесь не ться, а тся!